# Clicking On Specific Item Opens New Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have two different forms. One form names AllRecords, another named SprayRecords. In AllRecords, I have different operations, one of them being spray in a combo box got from a different table. When the operation is spray, click on it and a different form opens for the user to enter more detailed information about it. After they are done entering information, return to AllRecords form for more record entering. What kind of code would do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think if you research 'Cascading Combo Box' that might help

Comment: I am curious what code would be required on the After Update(?) field to only open a new form if spray is selected in said combo box.